# error when using ifelse to create new columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to generate some random data, where the value of the cells in 4 columns should be either 1 or 0. But for each row, only one of the four columns can be 1. The chance should be equally distributed, so about 25% for each column. I've tried to do this using ifelse, but every time i run it, one of the columns always comes up with only zeros. It's a different column every time, too. Can anyone help me with this?

```
df <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$var1 <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df), prob = c(0.75,0.25), replace = T)
df$var2 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 1, 0, sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.67,0.33), replace = T))
df$var3 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 1 | df$var2 == 1, 0, sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.5,0.5), replace = T))
df$var4 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 1 | df$var2 == 1 | df$var3 == 1, 0, 1)
```

I'm trying to generate something like this:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| index | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|     1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|     2 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|     3 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|     4 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|     5 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|     6 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|     7 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|     8 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|     9 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|    10 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `sample` to get index of column number which would be 1 for a row and assign 0 to rest of the values. By doing this you ensure that there is only one 1 in the entire row.

```
no_of_columns <- 4
no_of_rows <- 10

create_row <- function(no_of_columns) {
  x <- numeric(length = no_of_columns)
  x[sample(1:no_of_columns, 1)] <- 1
  x
}

as.data.frame(t(replicate(no_of_rows, create_row(no_of_columns))))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1   0  0  0  1
#2   1  0  0  0
#3   1  0  0  0
#4   1  0  0  0
#5   0  1  0  0
#6   1  0  0  0
#7   0  0  1  0
#8   0  1  0  0
#9   0  0  1  0
#10  0  0  1  0
```

---

A shorter version of [OP's attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787853/3962914) could be

```
df <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), stringsAsFactors = F)
distribution <- sample(1:4, nrow(df), replace = T)
df[paste0("var", 1:4)] <- 0
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), distribution + 1)] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A second attempt using a different method worked, i used this code:

```
distribution <- sample(c(1,2,3,4), nrow(df), replace = T)
df$var1 <- ifelse(distribution == 1, 1, 0)
df$var2 <- ifelse(distribution == 2, 1, 0)
df$var3 <- ifelse(distribution == 3, 1, 0)
df$var4 <- ifelse(distribution == 4, 1, 0)
```

It first generates the distribution using numbers 1-4, and then the columns are filled in with 1s and 0s based on the values in the distribution.

Comment: Actually, yours is better, I added a shorter and scalable approach to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one column with '1', you can just sample a vector as many rows as you would like

```
V=c(0,0,0,1)
N = 20

df = data.frame(
index=1:N,
t(replicate(N,sample(V)))
)

rowSums(df[,-1])
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```